# Single code-behind to override class in the web project dll?

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to deploy changes to a single code-behind file when using a "web project" (i.e. the web project dll is in the bin) without deploying the whole dll?  Will the single file override the class in the dll if placed in the bin?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Perhaps there is a way to achieve what you want that doesn't require this.

Comment: Many files in the web project have changes, but those are not ready to be deployed yet - only a single file is.  I realize this can be handled with source control branching, but unfortunately that's not in place.  Worst case scenario, I'll have to pull the project source code that is currently deployed.  Just trying to see if there was a simpler way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't. Since it is part of the compiled DLL, you need to recompile and redeploy.

Putting the file in the `bin` folder will do nothing.

If you have a web farm, you could take some of the servers offline, update the application, put them back online and do the same with the remaining servers, so no downtime occurs (of course, you need to ensure that changes to shared code and systems can work with both versions of your code).